Auto Increment unique Id number. Country YYYY MM xxx
I have a ms.list where I want to have a unique id with.

2 fix lettres.
-2 lettres of the country chosen from à.list of choice.(ex: US for USA, NO for Normay)
YYYY For the year
MM for the month
xxxx 4 digits auto increment, with à reset à beginning of next month.

Thanks a lot
Pierre

Have you considered to use Power Automate (Flow)? Are the expected values would be like US2024100001, US2024100002, ..US2024110001..US2024110002..?
